# Spring WS with simple input parameters and return type

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I've developed a web service using Spring WS. Example endpoint operation looks like:

```
@ResponsePayload
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "SendSmsRequest")
public SendSmsResponse sendSms(@RequestPayload SendSmsRequest sendSmsRequest) {}
```

xsd for this operation:

```
<xs:element name="SendSmsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mobileNo" type="tns:MobileNoString" />
            <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="SendSmsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:BaseResponse" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Unfortunately I've been told by our partner company development team, that they cannot work with object types (!!!), that's why I must change all complex types to simple (multiple String input parameters and single String as return type).

I can do it using Jax-WS Metro project:

```
@WebMethod
public String sayHello(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
    return String.format("Hello, %s!", name);
}
```

Can I do it using Spring WS or I must switch to Metro?

Comment: Why would you need Spring WS for that? That is just a simple implementation of a Spring Controller. You don't really need SOAP for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your reply! I need a soap service with a WSDL file. Can you please provide additional information how can I implement it using spring mvc?

Comment: Then use spring-ws and define it as such in your wsdl. Also why wouldn't they be able to work with objects? If they can parse the wsdl...